# Does an information schema exist before it is queried?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-schema

In a SQL database, I can run a query to present information as it exists, and I can create new compilations of data that did not previously exist.

For instance, `SELECT * FROM Table1` would return information that already existed, while a series of nested joins and WHERE statements could present data in ways that didn't exist before the query was run.

My question is whether the database's information schema -- assuming it's never been pulled up before -- falls into the first category or the second.

Comment: Your statements are very confusing.  Try to ask your real question.

Comment: `SELECT` always works within existing databases.  It can modify the representation form of the data (including aggregation), but it does not introduce any new data.

Comment: Can you read a file if it doesn't exists? think `SELECT` is same like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information schema views query already existent system tables in database. You can control yourself as [sys.tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) etc which are called [catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx) in Sql server. 
Therefore using these views falls to second type of usage in your question. Using existent data in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is just a view on the system tables. So the answer to your question is both that the data has always been there (because every object in the database has one or more rows in system tables somewhere representing it) and also that it's generated for your viewing pleasure upon querying (to present it in the form that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` requires).

Note that even what we normally call "the system tables" (`sys.tables` and related) are also just views on the real, actual, physical system tables, which are not accessible to any user but only to the database engine itself -- viewing those directly requires a direct administrator connection and tweaking some flags, and is typically not something done by anyone other than SQL Server developers.

As to what this implies in a FOIA context is probably best answered in a legal setting, not an information-theoretical one.